# Determine content-type of page in middleware class Django

Tags: python, django

Well, I have middleware class which is required to determine content-type of rendered page
and if it is 'txt/html', then do some action. I've started just from seeing what content-types do I have on page and here is first problem I faced:

```
class StatsMiddleware(object):
    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
              response = view_func(request, *view_args, **view_kwargs)
              print response['Content-Type']
```

Executing this, I get few messages about content-types of page elements, like `text/html`, `application/javascript` and also 
tons of errors like `key error: content-type` and after that - `broken pipe`

So I assume that not all elements of page have such header `Content-Type` and my question is following:

Is there some general Content-Type that says 'That page is text/html' or there are a lot of content-types on page ?

And also if this is a proper way to deterimne content-type of page like this:

```
if response['Content-Type'] == 'text/html':
     pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why do you have those exceptions. According to [django source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/http/response.py#L111-L113) HttpResponse always have Content-Type. Default type sets in [settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE)

List of all mime-types you can find [here](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml). But I'm pretty sure that 'text/html' is what you need.

You can also check type of response at first, and then check for content-type using .get() function to avoid unnecessary exceptions:

```
if isinstance(response, HttpResponse):
  if response.get('Content-Type').count('text/html'):
     response=big_magic(response)
return response
```

Some tests:

```
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:14:40) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Django 1.7
>>> from django.http import response
>>> r = response.HttpResponse('some content')
>>> r['Content-Type']
'text/html; charset=utf-8'
>>> response.HttpResponseRedirect('/some/url')['Content-Type']
>>> response.HttpResponseRedirect('/some/url').get('Content-Type').count('text/html')
1
```

Answer (score -1):

'text/html' or 'xml' is text files. "Content-Type" is text in file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<note>
<to> Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

if "<?xml" in page then - xml else - html
```